# Views: Content grouped by 2nd level taxonomy term

Tags: views

I want to create a view that accepts parent taxonomy term as contextual filter. And it will show the content grouped by its child taxonomy terms.

For example if the taxonomy has

- Top Term1.0
  -- Term1.1
  -- Term1.2
- Top Term2.0
  --Term2.1
  --Term2.2

If the contextual filter is Top Term1 then content should be grouped by children terms Term1.1 and Term1.2
If the contextual filter is Top Term2 then content should be grouped by children terms Term2.1 and Term2.2

How can I achieve it by using views?